# PHP Sessions Login System

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to test a simple login system without a db, just for testing purposes. 
I have created a php file that checks if the username and pass are valid and register a session.

```
<?php
session_start();
define("ADMINUSER", "user");
define("ADMINPASSWORD", "pass");
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if (($user==ADMINUSER) && ($pass==ADMINPASSWORD))
{
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    header("Location: main.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: auth.php?flag=wrong");
}
?>
```

and include this in other files to check if the user is logged in:

```
<? session_start();
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != true)
{
    header("Location: auth.php?flag=not");
    exit;
}
?>
```

But this doesn't seem to work, as I close the window and try to open it again and it doesn't redirect me to the login page(auth.php).

What am I doing wrong ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to completely quit your browser and/or clear out cookies, not just close the one window.

Comment: At least you did not use `session_start()` in your other file before accessing $_SESSION.

Comment: Is the first header redirect working? Most clients need absolute URI's for the location i.e. header("Location: http://www.example.com/main.php")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't redirect you to the auth.php page since your session persists until you clear your browser's cookies or until the session runs out. Hence why closing the browser window won't log you off Facebook/Twitter etc.

Comment: What is the proper way to check if the user logged in and not accessing the page without proper credentials ?

Comment: I cleared my cookies and shutdown my computer and still the page isn't redirecting to the login form. Are you sure there isn't anything wrong in the script ?

Answer (score 5):

This part of your code:

```
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true;
```

Should be:

```
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

= is an assignment operator.

== is a comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use an exit after a redirecting with the header function, otherwise loading of the page will continue.

```
header('Location: auth.php', true, 303);
exit;
```

It's a good practise to specify the code 303, instead of redirecting with the default 301. Code 301 means "moved permanently", code 303 means "see other".